# Sort all text files by size, producing a text list of paths

Tags: macos, find, sorting

This gives me a list of paths to all text files:

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' > ~/Desktop/sorted.txt
```

I'd like to sort this path list according each item's file size, but I'm unsure what to use. This doesn't work as I would've expected:

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' |sort -S > ~/Desktop/sorted.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This command uses a separate `wc` process for each matching file, therefore its performance may be poor. I created it with compatibility and POSIX-compliance in mind.

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec wc -c {} \; | sort -t ' ' -n -k 1,1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Each `wc -c` generates a line in a form

```
12345 /path/to/file/possibly with spaces/foo.txt
```

where the first space separates the byte count from the path. `sort` gets all the lines, uses space character as the field separator and sorts numerically according to the first field, i.e. according to the byte counts. Then `cut` uses space character as field delimiter and prints from the second field, i.e. everything but the first field, i.e. everything but the byte counts, i.e. the paths.

The solution can be easily adapted to sort by line count: just use `wc -l` instead of `wc -c`.

---

Note:
A path containing one or more newline characters will break my code. To make the code immune to this, one could use tools that support null characters as delimiters. With POSIX tools this is hard, if possible at all. This answer concentrates on portability, so hopefully all paths to your text files are "nice".

Answer (score -1):

You can always go with the (probably suboptimal) approach of chaining tools together:

```
find / -type f -name '*.txt' -ls  | sort -nk7,7 | awk '{print $NF;}'
```

- The `-ls` switch on find will show a number of extra colums including file size (on GNU toolset, the 7th column, might be different on MacOS)
- The `sort` will do a numerical sort on the 7th column (file size)
- The `awk` removes all the other fields and only prints the file name

Comment: This seems like a very complex solution to what I assumed was a simple problem - do you think you could clarify what this process is? I am new to Bash code, so I need all the extra help I can get..

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I'm trying to adapt this code to macOS..
I seem to be able to sort by size now, but I am failing to understand how to use "cut" to remove the unnecessary information. 
`find / -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ls -lh {} \;|sort -k 5 -n| cut -f 2- > ~/Desktop/sorts/sorted.txt`

Comment: **Warning:** `awk '{print $NF;}'` will mangle paths that contain spaces.